# CUDA Mandelbrot set

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

This is a sequential Mandelbrot Set implementation.

```
 void mandelbrot(PGMData *I)
{
    float x0,y0,x,y,xtemp;
    int i,j;
    int color;
    int iter;
    int MAX_ITER=1000;  
    for(i=0; i<I->height; i++)
        for(j=0; j<I->width; j++)
        {
            x0 = (float)j/I->width*(float)3.5-(float)2.5; 
            y0 = (float)i/I->height*(float)2.0-(float)1.0;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            iter = 0;
            while((x*x-y*y <= 4) && (iter < MAX_ITER))
            { 
                xtemp = x*x-y*y+x0;
                y = 2*x*y+y0;
                x = xtemp;
                iter++;
            }
            color = (int)(iter/(float)MAX_ITER*(float)I->max_gray);
            I->image[i*I->width+j] = I->max_gray-color;
        }
}
```

I want to paralellize it using CUDA but I seem to have misunderstood something and now I'm stuck. I've tried searching the internet but nothing really great came up.

Kernel:

```
__global__ void calc(int *pos)
{
    int row= blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  // WIDTH
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  // HEIGHT
    int idx = row * WIDTH + col;

    if(col > WIDTH || row > HEIGHT || idx > N) return;

    float x0 = (float)row/WIDTH*(float)3.5-(float)2.5;
    float y0 = (float)col/HEIGHT*(float)2.0-(float)1.0; 

    int x = 0, y = 0, iter = 0, xtemp = 0;
    while((x*x-y*y <= 4) && (iter < MAX_ITER))
    { 
        xtemp = x*x-y*y+x0;
        y = 2*x*y+y0;
        x = xtemp;
        iter++;
    }
    int color = 255 - (int)(iter/(float)MAX_ITER*(float)255);
    __syncthreads();
    pos[idx] = color;//color;// - color;

}
```

The kernel is initiated this way:

```
dim3 block_size(16, 16);
dim3 grid_size((N)/block_size.x, (int) N / block_size.y);
calc<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(d_pgmData);
```

And here are the constants:

```
#define HEIGHT 512
#define WIDTH 512   
#define N (HEIGHT*WIDTH)
```

The whole GPU function

```
void mandelbrotGPU(PGMData *I)
{
    int *pos = (int *)malloc(HEIGHT*WIDTH*sizeof(int));
    int *d_pgmData;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pgmData, sizeof(int)*WIDTH*HEIGHT);


    cudaMemcpy(d_pgmData, pos ,HEIGHT*WIDTH*sizeof(int) ,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 block_size(16, 16);
    dim3 grid_size((N)/block_size.x, (int) N / block_size.y);
    calc<<<grid_size,block_size>>>(d_pgmData);

    cudaMemcpy(pos,d_pgmData,HEIGHT*WIDTH*sizeof(int) ,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_pgmData);
    I->image = pos;
}
```

The problem is: It's either returning garbage or the driver crashes. I would really appreciate some advice because I am really stuck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code (using OpenCV):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define HEIGHT 512 // must be multiple of block_size.y
#define WIDTH 512 // must be multiple of block_size.x
#define MAX_ITER 10000

void mandelbrotGPU(char*);
__global__ void calc(char* image_buffer);

#define cudaAssertSuccess(ans) { _cudaAssertSuccess((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void _cudaAssertSuccess(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line)
{
  if (code != cudaSuccess)  {
    fprintf(stderr,"_cudaAssertSuccess: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    exit(code);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  IplImage* image_output = cvCreateImage(cvSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
  mandelbrotGPU(image_output->imageData);
  cvShowImage("GPU", image_output);
  waitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&image_output);
}

void mandelbrotGPU(char* image_buffer)
{
  char* d_image_buffer;
  cudaAssertSuccess(cudaMalloc(&d_image_buffer, WIDTH * HEIGHT));
  dim3 block_size(16, 16);
  dim3 grid_size(WIDTH / block_size.x, HEIGHT / block_size.y);
  calc<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(d_image_buffer);
  cudaAssertSuccess(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  cudaAssertSuccess(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
  cudaAssertSuccess(cudaMemcpy(image_buffer, d_image_buffer, HEIGHT * WIDTH, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  cudaAssertSuccess(cudaFree(d_image_buffer));
}

__global__ void calc(char* image_buffer)
{
  int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  // WIDTH
  int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  // HEIGHT
  int idx = row * WIDTH + col;
  if(col >= WIDTH || row >= HEIGHT) return;

  float x0 = ((float)col / WIDTH) * 3.5f - 2.5f;
  float y0 = ((float)row / HEIGHT) * 3.5f - 1.75f;

  float x = 0.0f;
  float y = 0.0f;
  int iter = 0;
  float xtemp;
  while((x * x + y * y <= 4.0f) && (iter < MAX_ITER))
  { 
    xtemp = x * x - y * y + x0;
    y = 2.0f * x * y + y0;
    x = xtemp;
    iter++;
  }

  int color = iter * 5;
  if (color >= 256) color = 0;
  image_buffer[idx] = color;
}
```

Output:

[image: Mandelbrot output]

The most important changes:

- Removed `__syncthreads();`. This algorithm doesn't use the data generated by other threads, so there's no need to synchronize the threads.
- Removed the copying of the host buffer over to the device. It's not necessary since the Mandelbrot algorithm writes the entire device buffer.
- Fixed incorrect grid size calculation.
- Removed the malloc of host memory because the result is copied directly into the OpenCV image buffer.
- Changed the buffers to using bytes instead of ints, which is more convenient when you have a single gray channel with 8-bit resolution.
- Removed some uneccessary float casts. When you use integers in calculations together with floats, the integers get automatically promoted to floats.
- Fixed two issues in the Mandelbrot algorithm:

  - `x` and `y` were declared as `int`s while they should be `float`s.
  - The first expresssion in the `while` loop should contain a `+`, not a `-`.

Comment: Hi, could you please post the commands/tools that you used to build the project? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: whats this?: ``#include "device_launch_parameters.h" what does it contain?

Comment: @BitTickler Looks like it holds the declarations for blockIdx, blockDim, threadIdx, and gridDim;

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not correct:

```
    dim3 grid_size((N)/block_size.x, (int) N / block_size.y);
```

This is causing out-of-bounds accesses in your kernel.  You want to launch `WIDTH` x `HEIGHT` threads in total, one for each pixel in your image.  Instead you are launching `N`/16 x `N`/16 threads.

And it seems like you have a thread check line in your kernel (which should have prevented out-of-bounds accesses from errant threads), but it's not formulated correctly:

```
if(col > WIDTH || row > HEIGHT || idx > N) return;
```

For example this allows `idx` = `N` to pass the thread check, but this is *not* a valid memory location when written by the final line of the kernel:

```
pos[idx] = color;
```

You could fix this thread check with:

```
if(col >= WIDTH || row >= HEIGHT || idx >= N) return;
```

A few other comments:

- you're not doing any [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)
- you can see the error in your code if you run it with `cuda-memcheck`

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas to look at:

1. There is no need to `__syncthreads()`. Your threads in a block don't communicate with each other.
2. There is no need to create device memory for I_WIDTH and I_HEIGHT. You just pass them in as values (instead of as pointers or reference). You do need need device memory for `pos`.
3. You need to check for the return value of all your CUDA functions (eg, `cudaMalloc`) and make sure it is all ok.
4. When you launch a kernel, your program can return before your GPU finishes.  There are situations where you will need to wait explicitly for completion; you can do this by calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after launching.  In your case, you do not have to because your CUDA memcpy will wait until the kernel is completed.

Comment: Your item 4 isn't correct.  CUDA operations issued to the same stream (they are all in the same default stream here) are automatically serialized.  The `cudaMemcpy` operation will not begin until the `calc` kernel preceding it has finished.  There is no need for a call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after launching if the concern is waiting for the kernel to finish.